# Ruby on Rails - Rakefile validates_uniqueness_of

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, rake, rakefile, validates-uniqueness-of

I am using a rakefile to fetch information from one website and saving it to my database.

Using the TMDB-Gem, this code `@movie = TmdbMovie.browse(:order_by => "release", :order => "asc", :page => 1, :per_page => 2, :language => "en", :expand_results => true)` browses the oldest movies (`:order_by => "release"`) and saves them to my database, but as i'll be running this rake quite frequently, the returned and saved movies will be the same.

Every movie has a `tmdb_id` and every `id` is unique

How can i make the rakefile check that the returned movie's tmdb_id is unique, and if there is already a movie with that id, skip and save the next movie.

I tried it in my Movies model `validates_uniqueness_of :tmdb_id` but it gives an error when running the rake command and it doesn't save movies.

Basically, how can I, through the rakefile, validate the uniqueness of the tmdb_id

This is my rake file

```
namespace :db do 

task :pull_tmdb_data => :environment do 

Tmdb.api_key = "API KEY" 



Tmdb.default_language = "en" 

  @movie = TmdbMovie.browse(:order_by => "release", :order => "asc", :page => 1, :per_page => 2, :language => "en", :expand_results => true)



@movie.each do |movie| 

Movie.create(title: movie.name, description: movie.overview, release_date: movie.released, tmdb_id: movie.id) 

end 



end 

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right to use `validates_uniqueness_of :tmdb_id` in your `Movie` model. You didn't show how you were saving the movies to your database, but `.save` doesn't cause an exception when validations fail, whereas `.save!` does. The key would be to use a save method that doesn't raise an error when validations fail.

Edit - Now that I understand what you're actually trying to do, you should be able to do something like:

```
per_page = 100
number_of_movies = Movie.count
page = number_of_movies/per_page+1
@movies = TmdbMovie.browse(:order_by => "release", :order => "asc", :page => page, :per_page => per_page, :language => "en", :expand_results => true) browses the oldest movies (:order_by => "release")
```

So if you've already pulled 435 movies, it'll only return movies 400-500 in the next call .. I did it this way because I wasn't sure if there was an `offset` option, but if there is you could just offset the query by `Movie.count`, which would be better.

Comment: Added my rake file to the question. Using `validates_uniqueness_of :tmdb_id` causes the rake command to NOT save the returned movies, whereas if i remove `validates_uniqueness_of :tmdb_id` it saves it

Comment: `create` shouldn't raise an exception, can you please show us the error you get?

Comment: It doesnt return an error. What happens is that, if i dont have the validates... in the model, then push to heroku and run the rake command, it saves the returned movies to my database, like it should do. BUT, if i add validates_uni... to my model, then push to heroku and run the rake command, it DOESNT save the returned movies to my database

Comment: So you lied in your question? _"I tried it in my Movies model validates_uniqueness_of :tmdb_id but it gives an error when running the rake command and it doesn't save movies"_? What do you want to happen and what isn't happening currently that you want to happen?

Comment: I wouldn't call that lying, just a mistake.

Comment: Ok, mistake aside, what are you trying to achieve, what's the problem? I still don't understand the question. You say in your question: _"How can i make the rakefile check that the returned movie's tmdb_id is unique, and if there is already a movie with that id, skip and save the next movie."_, surely this is what happens with the validation in the model?

Comment: I run the rake command `rake db:pull_tmdb_data`, what this does is it browses **the 2 oldest movies** then saves them. If i run this again, it saves those same 2 movies, what i want it to do is save the 2 other oldest movies and not the ones already saved. If i put validates_uniquess.. in my model, in doesnt save any returned movie.

Comment: Oh, that has got nothing to do with validations, that's just because you're pulling the same TMDB data, you'll need to adjust your query to pull different records... `:page => 2` perhaps? The whole thing seems like a bad idea anyway. Why are you only pulling two records each time?

Comment: Thats just for testing purposes, when i launch it will obviously run to return more movies. But say i collect 100 movies, run that command, then save 100 movies.

Comment: What if a new movie arrives, then i run it again and i'll have 201 movies.
The old 100 movies + the new 101 returned movies